# How to run PDF to TIFF conversion in parallel?

Tags: shell-script, conversion, parallelism

I have this command here for batch converting PDF documents (first 2 pages) to TIFF files using `pdftoppm`.

The goal is to put the TIFF images into its own folder with folder name matching the original PDF file name.

```bsh
for file in *.pdf; do
    pdftoppm -tiff -f 1 -l 2 "$file" ~/tiff/directory/"$file"/"$file"
done
```

How can I run 8 instances of the `pdftoppm` command concurrently?

I am running Debian.
I have 10000s of PDFs to convert to TIFF.

Comment: You can't. What you can do is run the same, single threaded, loop multiple times in parallel. Please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system you are using, how many files you have, what kind of upper limit you have for parallelization (is this 10 files? 1000000 files? How many processes can your machine support before dying?). If we know that, we can suggest some approaches.

Comment: I edited the post as requested @terdon

Comment: xargs may be an option - see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28357997

Comment: @Anonymous
I tried to use xargs
```ls -b | xargs -n 1 -P 8 pdftoppm -tiff -f 1 -l 2```  
this resulted in an error because I couldn't specify the output folder. any suggestions for this?

Comment: first I would check if pdftoppm can take multiple input files as argument. second I would try find exec or find xargs

Comment: I sort have figured out a crude solution. 
Go to the working directory, then ```ls -b > filenames.txt``` . 

then ```while read x; do pdftoppm -tiff -f 1 -l 2 ${x:Q} ~/tiff/directory/{x:q}; done < filenames.txt```

Any suggestions to improve this while loop would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to create the shell input for all the jobs:

```
for file in *.pdf
do
    printf 'pdftoppm -tiff -f 1 -l 2 "%q" ~/tiff/directory/"%q"/"%q"' \
        "$file" "$file" "$file"
done
```

and then pipe that to `parallel -j N` where N is the number of jobs you want to run simultaneously:

```
for file in *.pdf
do
    printf 'pdftoppm -tiff -f 1 -l 2 "%q" ~/tiff/directory/"%q"/"%q"' \
        "$file" "$file" "$file"
done |
parallel -j 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `parallel`:

```bsh
printf '%s\0' ./*.pdf |
parallel --null --jobs 8 \
    pdftoppm -tiff -f 1 -l 2 '{}' ~/tiff/directory/'{/.}'/'{/.}'.tiff
```

The above command pipeline would run your `pdftoppm` command across all filenames matching `*.pdf` in the current directory.  The `'{}'` expands to the current pathname while `'{/.}'` expands to the basename of the current pathname, with the filename suffix removed.  So if the current filename is `./file-02.pdf`, then `'{}'` would be `'./file-02.pdf'` while `'{/.}'` would be `file-02`.

I'm feeding `parallel` with nul-delimited pathnames from `printf` to be able to cope with any possible filename.  These are read with `--null` by `parallel`.

I took some liberties with what the destination pathname should be. You should adjust that to what you actually want to use.

Comment: Is it possible to get just the extension using some {} macro?

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин No. You could use `{= expr =}` where `expr` is a Perl expression, to compute it.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин Yes: `echo a.b | parallel --plus echo {+.}` (version > 20140722).

Comment: The man page is so huge, I never got to the part about --plus and {} macros. This is sweet! Will cite, Ole ;)

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин I did not mention `{+.}` as it does not do the right thing for a pathname containing no extension (it returns the pathname unchanged rather than an empty string).

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин What needs to happen is to extract the root of the filename, including the directory path, up to the last dot in the filename (or the whole pathname if there is no dot in the filename), then to delete that prefix string from the pathname.  This is just a tiny bit more complex than what the `{X}` macros in `parallel` can currently do it seems.  In `zsh`, you'd do `$pathname:e` to get the extension from `$pathname`.

Comment: @they You have found a bug. Thanks.

Comment: @OleTange It's not a bug. I believe `{+.}` behaves as advertised. There simply is no `{X}` macro to extract the filename suffix. So it's more of a "missing feature".

Comment: @they Check git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/parallel.git